# Powershell regex replace : string is unchanged

Tags: regex, powershell, global, multiline, regexp-replace

I'm trying to regex replace some groups of charactes in powershell using the following pattern:

[/^(thedir[ ]*=[ ]*")(.)(:[/\])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([/\]?.*)$/gm](https://regex101.com/r/htwMtQ/2)

by using this instruction:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content $fileToProcess -Raw 
$fileContent -replace '(?m)^(thedir[ ]*=[ ]*")(.)(:[\/\\])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([\/\\]?.*)$', '$1Z$3Here$5'
Write-Host "New file content is $fileContent"
```

but it fails doing anything at execution : $fileContent remains unchanged. I note that the `/gm` flags are important, and are missing in my instruction, but I don't find how to set them. I've tried to prefix the regex with `(?m)` without success (and also tried `(?smi)`, why not :)):

```
$fileContent -replace '(?m)^(thedir[ ]*=[ ]*")(.)(:[\/\\])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([\/\\]?.*)$', '$1Z$3Here$5'
```

As an example, let's process a `my.ini` containing:

```
[mysqld]
#skip-innodb

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
max_allowed_packet=16M


#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
#basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/"
basedir="C:/MySQL/"

#Path to the database root
#datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
datadir="C:/MySQLData/"

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
default-character-set=utf8
```

and replacing `thedir` in the matching string by `basedir`

For expected result see [here](https://regex101.com/r/htwMtQ/3)

As for now, I don't have any change in the $fileContent using the previsouly mentionned instructions.

Can you help me to make this work?

Comment: Instead of using a Regex, why not use .Net's file management classes? Those are aware of different path separators, drive letters and as such will return well-formed data.

Comment: @vonPryz: I have no concern changing the way of doing this, as far as it works :)

Comment: `$fileContent` is a single multiline text, right? Or is it just a single line? Next, `[ ]` is a space, right? What if there are other types of whitespace here? Try replacing with `[\p{Zs}\t]`.

Comment: Without giving an example of what `fileContent` you expect to be replaced from/to, this makes your question very difficult to understand, and hard to know if a proposed solution actually works.

Comment: @TomLord: filecontent is any text based file (but mainly configuration files).

Comment: on my 7.4.1 it works even without the `(m)?`, so i'd say the issue is in `$FileContent`.   I also suggest changing `[a-zA-Z]` to [^\/\\]` so to cover numbers, special characters, spaces, etc.

Comment: The first pattern appears to work just fine against the input in the linked regex101 test, I have the same results as @sirtao in both 7.5-preview1 and 5.1.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: yes, but doesn't work with Powershell

Comment: @sirtao:thank you, but I don't want to cover special characters, spaces, ... Also I edited the question to show how I get the text file content.

Comment: @TomLord: The problem is not the regex itself, but the fact that I have a matching string that works fine, but that I obviously don't succeed to translate in Powershell

Comment: @Oliver [It really does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRcrg.png)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: would the problem be the way I get the datas ? Using Get-Content $fileToProcess -Raw  ?

Comment: @Oliver If you use `-Raw` then you _definitely_ need `(?m)...`, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @Oliver My issue is that it's difficult to understand what you're trying to do. You have not provided an example of what `fileContent` might contain, i.e. what strings you're trying to match with the pattern. It is not easy to understand what `/^(thedir[ ]=[ ]")(.)(:[/\])([a-zA-Z0-9])([/\]?.)$/gm` means, let alone what's apparently "wrong" with it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Add a real example of the file you are reading and below that what the **expected** result should be and what the current (wrong) result is that you are getting.

Comment: None of the lines in the sample file you've provided starts with `thedir` - so why are you using that in your pattern?

Comment: @Theo: done, question edited

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Yes, the answer is in the edit and the provided link

Comment: @Oliver No one is gonna help you if you keep being this unwilling to provide relevant details. Your question still doesn't contain the expected input

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: What do you want more ? I gave a real example, a regex101 sample, the code I use ? What else ?

Comment: I'd like enough information that I can reproduce your issue - instead, I have a pattern that you're _not_ using, along with some sample data you _might_ be using (still can't tell if the ini file is the input or the strings on the first regex101 is), and an extremely vague description of what happens (nothing).

Comment: Heads up: `-replace` doesn't mutate the string in-place - you need to assign the output back to the variable if you want it to persist: `$fileContent = $fileContent -replace ...`

Comment: As aside.. Why don't you use backslashes in file paths as is common in Windows ?

Comment: @Theo:because sometimes these are not backslashes in some config files

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen:Great, that was the problem. As you can see (and as I expected), you didn't need so much details about the question to figure out where was problem. You can post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I never said I needed _much_ detail, I said _relevant details_ - like for example an explanation of what it is you're _expecting_ to happen. If you'd said "the contents of `$fileContents` remain the same even though I expected it to change" up front I could have told you the same :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I understand your point. I assumed when writing the question that saying that a -replace instruction fails doing anything at execution obviously meant that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the pattern works perfectly fine against the sample values in the linked regex101 test suite:

[image]

Beware that `-replace` doesn't have side-effects - it doesn't modify the left-hand side variable in-place (like perl's `=~` for example).

To store the resulting string(s), remember to re-assign them to a new or existing variable:

```
$newFileContents = $fileContents -replace '(?m)^(thedir[ ]*=[ ]*")(.)(:[\/\\])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([\/\\]?.*)$', '$1Z$3Here$5'
Write-Host "New file contents is:`n$($newFileContents -join "`n")"
```